# Can I have duplicated markup using schema.org?

Tags: seo, javascript, schema.org, google-tag-manager, markup

I have this:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">

    <meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" content="true">

    <span itemprop="author publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
      <meta itemprop="url" content="http://axample.com.br">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="axample">
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://facebook.com/axample" />
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://twitter.com/axample" />
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://www.instagram.com/axample" />
      <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://axample.com.br/axample.png">
        <meta itemprop="width" content="151">
        <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
      </span>
    </span>

    <span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <meta itemprop="url" content="http://axample.com.br/axample.png">
      <meta itemprop="width" content="200">
      <meta itemprop="height" content="150">              
    </span>
    <meta itemprop="description" content="A description">
</span>
```

I use a JavaScript to get the meta tags and insert on JASON-LD. I'm using the Element DOM on Google Tag Mannger and I configured the Element DOM to get the `meta[itemprop="url"]`. This will get the first meta tag that has the `itemprop="url"`.

I heard that there's a correct order to put the markup in HTML, then I was thinking if I can duplicate the meta tag from the ImageObject and put it above.

```
<span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">   //duplicated
  <meta itemprop="url" content="http://axample.com.br/axample.png">         //duplicated
  <meta itemprop="width" content="200">                                    //duplicated
  <meta itemprop="height" content="150">                                  //duplicated        
</span>
<meta itemprop="description" content="A description">

<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">

    <meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" content="true">

    <span itemprop="author publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
      <meta itemprop="url" content="http://axample.com.br">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="axample">
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://facebook.com/axample" />
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://twitter.com/axample" />
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://www.instagram.com/axample" />
      <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://axample.com.br/axample.png">
        <meta itemprop="width" content="151">
        <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
      </span>
    </span>

    <span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <meta itemprop="url" content="http://axample.com.br/axample.png">
      <meta itemprop="width" content="200">
      <meta itemprop="height" content="150">              
    </span>
    <meta itemprop="description" content="A description">
</span>
```

I saw this duplicated meta tag on another popular website in my country.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement "*I use a JavaScript to get the meta tags and insert on JASON-LD.*" confuses me.    If you already have the Schema.org mark up in your page(s) in Microdata format, the search engines will consume it.

Schema.org is valid in all three formats: Microdata, RDFa, JSON-LD.  If it is already in one format there is no need to convert it to another.

Yes, Google prefer you use JSON-LD but that is a preference not a requirement.

Also, although you can mix formats on a single page, you **should not** repeat the same data in multiple formats. (*looking for where that is stated but can't find a link at the moment*)

As to statement ordering, yes it is important but only to ensure that the *itemprop*s are nested within the appropriate *itemscope*.

The effect of the [2nd] code you show is to say that there are two *ImageObject*s.  One is just a random ImageObject definition, the other being the *image* of the *NewsArticle* - which doesn't make sense.

If you want to indicate that a particular entity is the most important (from many) on a page[mainEntity](https://schema.org/mainEntity) property.

Hope this helps.

BTW 'true' is not an expected value for [mainEntityOfPage](https://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage)

Comment: **BTW 'true' is not an expected value for mainEntityOfPage** Then why i see it on some websites? I see it on JSON-ld and on inline markup.

Comment: It's also on Washington Post

Comment: Being used that way does not mean it's correct. Check the provided link for the specification.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath Yea, i searched a little and most websites put a URL on the `mainEntityOfPage`, then i really don't know why  some famous websites would use `true` on it.